# Check if two file paths resolve to the same file

Tags: r, windows, filepath

Say I have three file paths:

```
setwd("C:/superlongdirname")
files <- c("C:/superlongdirname/myfile.txt", "C:\\SUPERL~1\\myfile.txt", "./myfile.txt")
```

These all point to the same file. How, given multiple references to the same file, can I check that they are indeed referring to the same file within R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the full version of the filepaths and compare:

```
normalizePath(files[1]) == normalizePath(files[2])
```