# Check if two paths resolve to the same directory

Tags: r, filesystems

In [Check if two file paths resolve to the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095537/check-if-two-file-paths-resolve-to-the-same-file) the solution is to use `normalizePath`; however, this appears  to not be definitive for directories:

```r
td1 <- tempdir()
td2 <- paste0(td1, "/")

dir.exists(td1) && dir.exists(td2)
#> [1] TRUE
file.create(file.path(td1, "foo.txt"))
#> [1] TRUE
file.exists(file.path(td2, "foo.txt"))
#> [1] TRUE

normalizePath(td1) == normalizePath(td2)
#> [1] FALSE

sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252   
#> [3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
#> [5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] compiler_3.5.1  backports_1.1.2 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.3-2
#>  [5] tools_3.5.1     htmltools_0.3.6 yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_0.12.18   
#>  [9] stringi_1.1.7   rmarkdown_1.10  knitr_1.20      stringr_1.3.1  
#> [13] digest_0.6.16   evaluate_0.11
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-05 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).</sup>

Is there a method that is reliable (or more reliable) at identifying directories?

Comment: Example was run on Windows. Confirmed I get `TRUE` on Ubuntu.

Comment: The only difference is the final backslash. Just remove it if there is any (for instance with `gsub("\\\\$","",filepath)`) and you can reliably compare paths.

Comment: Confirmed I get 4 TRUEs on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're open to using a package for this, I'm having a lot of success with the [fs](https://fs.r-lib.org) package for path operations that are robust across OSes. When it normalizes via `fs::path_norm()`, it will strip this trailing slash on Windows, for example.

```r
td1 <- tempdir()
td2 <- paste0(td1, "/")

dir.exists(td1) && dir.exists(td2)
#> [1] TRUE
file.create(file.path(td1, "foo.txt"))
#> [1] TRUE
file.exists(file.path(td2, "foo.txt"))
#> [1] TRUE

normalizePath(td1) == normalizePath(td2)
#> [1] FALSE

library(fs)
path_norm(td1) == path_norm(td2)
#> [1] TRUE

sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
#> [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
#> [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
#> [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
#> [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] compiler_3.4.3  backports_1.1.2 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.3-2
#>  [5] tools_3.4.3     htmltools_0.3.6 yaml_2.1.16     Rcpp_0.12.18   
#>  [9] stringi_1.1.6   rmarkdown_1.8   knitr_1.17      stringr_1.2.0  
#> [13] digest_0.6.16   evaluate_0.10.1
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-05 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).</sup>